# Why does postgres (with sequelize) count 1 if there is no value?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize to count the number of messages that a device received during the last 24 hours.

Sequelize is going to execute the following request (I attached sequelize code at the end)

```
SELECT "device"."id", COUNT('records.id') AS "count"
FROM "device" AS "device"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "record" AS "records" ON "device"."id" = "records"."deviceId" AND "records"."date" > '2017-07-06 08:09:40.468 +00:00'
WHERE "device"."typeId" = '2'
GROUP BY "device"."id";
```

which return

```
id   count
24  25790
163 1
95  1
```

the value for the id `24` is correct, but the other values should be 0.

I then manually execute this SQL query

```
SELECT device.id, COUNT(record.id) AS count
FROM device AS device
  LEFT OUTER JOIN record ON device.id = record."deviceId" AND record.date > '2017-07-06 08:09:40.468 +00:00'
WHERE device."typeId" = '2'
GROUP BY device.id;
```

which gives me the expected result.

I'm not able to see the difference between the two queries. Does someone know why the second is working?

---

The sequelize request is the following

```
const devices = await this.database.model('device').findAll({
  where: {
    typeId: req.params.id,
  },
  attributes: {
    include: [
      'id',
      [this.database.fn('COUNT', 'records.id'), 'count'],
    ],
  },
  include: [{
    model: this.database.model('record'),
    where: {
      date: {
        $gt: oneDayAgo,
      },
    },
    attributes: [],
    required: false,
  }],
  group: ['device.id'],
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL has single quotes around `records.id`, so SQL is counting a string value (which is never `NULL`).  You want:

```
SELECT "device"."id", COUNT(records.id) AS "count"
```

I don't know how to express this in sequelize, but the problem is the single quotes.

Comment: I need to use `this.database.col('records', 'id')` in my sequelize to make it work. I will accept the answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it in sequelize would be by passing `'records.id'` to `this.database.col()`. By that Sequelize shouldn't quote identifier.

Actually you should use this function with each and every column you pass to Sequelize. By doing that Sequelize can generate more accurate queries.